# no output to file java

Tags: java, file

Im trying to read an answer key from a file and each row by comparing it to the last row and sending it to a file. I try sending to the file but there is no output, not sure what the problem is here?
 enter code here

```
`import java.util.Scanner;
```

import java.io.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class tester3{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{

```
    final int answer_size = 20;
    final int class_size = 20;

    final int answer_key_size = 20;

    String [][] answers = new String[answer_size][class_size];
    String [] correctAns = new String[20];

    readArray(answers);
    getAnswers(answers, correctAns);
    compareAnswers(answers, correctAns);


}

//read file ans into char array
public static void readArray(String[][] ar)throws IOException{
    File file = new File("answers.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    int index = 0;
    while(inputFile.hasNextInt() && index < ar.length){
    for(int row = 0; row < ar.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < ar[row].length; col++){
            ar[row][col] = inputFile.nextLine();
            index++;
            //ar[row][col] = Character.toString(ar[row][col].charAt(row));
            System.out.println(ar[row][col]);
        }
    }
}

}

//read last row into 1d array
public static void getAnswers(String[][] ar, String [] ar2)throws IOException{
            File file = new File("answers.txt");
            Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
            int index = 0;
            while(inputFile.hasNextInt() && index < ar.length){
            for(int row = 0; row < ar.length; row++){
                for(int col = 0; col < ar[row].length; col++){
                    //ar[row][col] = inputFile.nextLine().charAt(row);
                    if(row == 20){
                        inputFile.nextLine();
                        ar2[row] = Character.toString(ar[row][col].charAt(row));
                    }
                }
                index++;
            }
}

}
 //compare answers and send the results to an output file
public static void compareAnswers(String[][] ar, String [] ar2)throws IOException{
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("results.txt");
    File file = new File("answers.txt");
    int [] grades = new int[20];
                    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
                    int index = 0;
                    int count = 0;

                    writer.println("STUDENT EXAM RESULTS");
                    writer.println("Student number ----  # correct answers ---- Grade Received");

                    while(inputFile.hasNextInt() && index < ar.length){
                    for(int row = 0; row < ar.length; row++){
                        for(int col = 0; col < ar[row].length; col++){
                            ar[row][col] = Character.toString(ar[row][col].charAt(row));
                            if(ar[row][col].equals(ar2[row])){
                                count++;
                                grades[row] = (count/20) * 100;
                                writer.println(ar[row][col] + "----" + count + "----" + grades[row]);
                                writer.flush();
                            }
                        }
                        count = 0;
                        index++;
                    }
}

    writer.close();

}
```

}

Comment: @Karan: why do you make such a statement? Since when can a File not be parsed by a Scanner object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read the content of a file for example a TXT file you should use `BufferedReader`. You can do something like this:

```
public ArrayList<String> getFileLines(String filePath) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<>();
    String line = "";
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    while((line=in.readLine()) != null) {
        content.add(line);
    }
    return content;
}
```

Where `filePath` could be the absolute path of the file you want to read and returns the content of a file as an `ArrayList` of strings which is easy to handle.

Then if you want to write something on a file (again) for example a TXT file, you should use `BufferedWriter`.

```
public void writeArrayInFile(String filePath, ArrayList<String> content) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter(filePath) );
    for (String l : content) {
        out.write(l + "\n");
    }
    out.close();
}
```

In this case `filePath` should be the absolute path of the file that you want to create but be careful if the file already exist this method will overwrite the content of the file. And the `ArrayList<String>` is just the content that you want to write.